# Error when using GetComponent (Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

Tags: unity, javascript, objects

I'm using a textmesh to check variables in real time. Thing is if I use AddComponent within Update(), it obviously starts spamming and slows the game. If I try with GetComponent the error is the following:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>
> DebugCombo.Update() (at Assets/DebugCombo.js:9)

which points to the `text.text` assignment.

This is the script from DebugCombo.js, from which I call the Combo class (from Combo.js)

```
#pragma strict

public class DebugCombo extends MonoBehaviour{

    function Update () {
        var text = gameObject.GetComponent(TextMesh);
        var combo = gameObject.GetComponent(Combo);
    
        text.text = "Current: "+ Time.time +" | Limit: " + combo.comboTime;
    }

}
```

How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer because I'm unsure, but when declaring a variable, you need to also say what type it is. Try using `var text:TextMesh = gameObject.GetComponent(TextMesh);` and `var combo:Combo = gameObject.GetComponent(Combo);`. Does this fix it?

Comment: Eh, if you're reading this, come join the gamedev chatroom for some instant help :D http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem not to have a TextMesh component in your game object, and you are not checking if `GetComponent` method has returned any. You can add it once at runtime if it doesn't exist:

```
var text = gameObject.GetComponent(TextMesh);
if( text == null )
{
    text = gameObject.AddComponent(TextMesh);
}
```

Or to make it better, you can make `var text` a private class variable to cache it, and not to call `GetComponent` all the time.

The second way, is to make `text` and `combo` a public class variables, and then drag and drop the proper instances in the editor. Then, you wouldn't have to call any `Add/GetComponent` calls at runtime, because you would already have them attached.

Anyway, you should always check if `GetComponent` has returned something, and if not you should call `Debug.LogError("Your error message here")` to avoid NullPointer exception and application crash.